# create crtl+c and ctrl+v shortcuts (adaptive technology)

Tags: linux, shell-script, mouse

I have a rare disease on my right wrist and I am using the mouse with my left hand. It works ok, but the problem is when I need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. I keep switching my left hand from mouse to the keyboard and my working performance has fallen.

I am use Kubuntu and I am looking to change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to be only the "c" key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to be only the "v" key.

What do you think, it's that something possible ? What are the suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: If you make `ctrl-c` be only the "c" key (and similarly for "v"), how will you ever type a literal "c" (or "v") character?

Comment: The default behavior should be highlight-to-copy and middle-click-to-paste, have you tried using that?

Answer (score 1):

A)  [Mousetweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Mousetweaks), included in Kubuntu and Ubuntu ([18.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/mousetweaks)) ([19.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mousetweaks/3.32.0-1)), may be helpful. If you select a location (for a Paste) or block of test (for a Copy action), a mouse gesture can be defined in its Control Panel to perform a Copy or a Paste.

B) Would you consider a [multi-button programmable mouse](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_technology) ([one vendor's list](http://bestbuy.com/site/shop/mouse-with-programmable-buttons), from many)?  They're gotten quite inexpensive and allow you to assign combination keystrokes to specific mouse buttons. That would remove the complication of when you need to type C as C and V as V.

C) And, then, there are [Foot Mice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footmouse):
[FooTime](https://www.fentek-ind.com/footime.htm#.XS47oh1KhPY)  ([review](https://www.disabled-world.com/assistivedevices/computer/footime.php))
[Pedal Only](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IK208WK)
[Double Pedal Only](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07553KW32)
among others.

*None of these links are affiliate links, I receive no compensation of any kind from these links.*